# How do we get the url params in nodejs via typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have this onRequest method written below,

```
      onRequest(request: Http.IncomingMessage, response: Http.ServerResponse): void {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        const tc = new TaxCalculator();
        const tax = JSON.stringify(tc.calculate(request.amount, request.rate));
        res.send(tax);
      }
```

I get the error with the above method
Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'.

My question is how do we get the amount and rate params passed through url?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 and Express, try this destructuring approach:

```
   const { amount, rate } = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
```

in code:

```
  var url = require('url');

  onRequest(request: Http.IncomingMessage, response: Http.ServerResponse): void {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        const tc = new TaxCalculator();
        const queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
        const { amount, rate } = queryData;
        const tax = JSON.stringify(tc.calculate(amount, rate));
        res.send(tax);
      }
```

Comment: it complains request.query doesn't exist on type IncomingMessage

Comment: try now, changed to params

Comment: now params.query doesn't exist on type IncomingMessage

Comment: try now with url change